# How to get rows depending on the "Total" Field using an Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, delphi, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables:

TABLE A

| ID | DESCRIPTION | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

TABLE B

| ID | DESCRIPTION | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

I use Delphi `TcxGrid` (GRID 1) to show all Table A rows, and I have another Grid (GRID 2) showing the Table B rows, When I select one row and double-click it in GRID1, a secondary window appears to ask the quantity to assign to the TABLE B, then the GRID 2 must show the row with the ID and the TOTAL typed by the user. Then I save the changes and the GRID1 must appear with the updated TOTAL = (TOTAL - Quantity typed).

NOTE: when the GRID 1 TOTAL of a row is 0, it has to disappear.

How can I afford that?

I've been trying with the MINUS Operator in the Query SQL that feeds the GRID 1 (TABLE A MINUS TABLE B), but it just doesn't show the row at the moment it's assigned to the GRID 2 (Table B)

Comment: You have to refresh the query attached to Table A after modifying Table B. Queries are static - once you do a SELECT, it won't know about any changes until that SELECT is run again.